# sql query for monthly data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written this query that gives day wise data of all 365 days of all 12 months when i select a year from drop down list.

```
SELECT
      YEAR(Date) AS [Year]
    , MONTH(Date) AS [Month]
    , COUNT(*) AS [Total]
FROM EnquiryMaster
WHERE EnquiryOwner = '" + enqowner + "'
     AND DATEPART(yyyy, Date) = '" + year + "'
     AND orgid = '" + orgid + "'
GROUP BY
      YEAR(Date)
    , MONTH(Date)

UNION ALL

SELECT
      YEAR(Date) AS [Year]
    , NULL
    , COUNT(*)
FROM EnquiryMaster
WHERE EnquiryOwner = '" + enqowner + "'
     AND DATEPART(yyyy, Date) = '" + year + "'
     AND orgid = '" + orgid + "'
GROUP BY YEAR(Date)
```

I want to write a query that will select month also along with year and display data only for that month

Comment: which datatype you are using for column date ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want, assuming I understood the question

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(yyyy, Date), 
    DATEPART(mm, Date),
    COUNT(*) AS [Total]
FROM EnquiryMaster
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(yyyy, Date), 
    DATEPART(mm, Date)
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(yyyy, Date), DATEPART(mm, Date)
```

Comment: DATEPART(mm, Date)],  comma missing in select statement

Comment: it is giving month wise total. i want month wise and day wise.......i want to retrieve data of all 30 or 31 days of month

Answer (score 0):

if you want result for only one month then put it in where clause (1 for jan, 2 for feb)

```
SELECT
      YEAR(Date) AS [Year]
    , MONTH(Date) AS [Month]
    , COUNT(*) AS [Total]
FROM EnquiryMaster
WHERE EnquiryOwner = '" + enqowner + "'
     AND DATEPART(yyyy, Date) = '" + year + "'
     AND orgid = '" + orgid + "'
     AND MONTH(Date) = '" + month + "'
GROUP BY
      YEAR(Date)
    , MONTH(Date)

UNION ALL

SELECT
      YEAR(Date) AS [Year]
    , NULL
    , COUNT(*)
FROM EnquiryMaster
WHERE EnquiryOwner = '" + enqowner + "'
     AND DATEPART(yyyy, Date) = '" + year + "'
     AND orgid = '" + orgid + "'
      AND MONTH(Date) = '" + month + "'
GROUP BY YEAR(Date)
```